# POST request not working in form

Tags: apache, http, post, web, get

I'm trying to submit some form using POST method. Here is par of form:

```
<form action="interlopers.php" mehod="post"  id = "interlopersForm" name="interlopersForm" onsubmit="return validateInterlopersForm()">
                <table border="0"> 
                    <tr> 
                         <td> <label for="ast_num" > Ast. num </label> </td>
                         <td> <input type="text" name="ast_num" id = "ast_num"
                                     value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['ast_num'])) { echo htmlentities ($_REQUEST['ast_num']); } ?>"
                                                  size="6"> </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr> 
                      <td><label for="cut_off"> Cut-off </label></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="cut_off"  id="cut_off" size="6" ></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr> 
                      <td><label for="data"> Data </label></td>
                      <td><input type ="checkbox" name="data" id = "dataSDSS" value="SDSS" checked> SDSS <br>
                       <input type ="checkbox" name="data" id="dataWISE" value="WISE" checked > WISE <br>
                       <input type ="checkbox" name="data" id = "dataSp" value="Sp" checked> Taxonomy</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td> <label for="isFinalStep"> Just interlopers? </label> </td>
                      <td> <input type = "checkbox" name="isFinalStep" id = "isFinalStep"> </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr> <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"> </tr>
                     <tr> 
                      <td colspan="2" align="center">     <input  type="submit" value="Calculate" > </td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

But, instead of getting POST request im getting GET request. I'm using apache server and php5 on Ubuntu. I tried this on local-server and on remote host, but still GET instead of POST.

Comment: You have a typo on your form attribute "method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mehod="post" to method="post".

You wrote wrong.

Comment: Thank you, i havent noticed it!